# Is my website internationalization plan coherent?

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization

I’m creating websites in PHP since some years but I never had to manage multi-language scenarios. I plan to create from scratch a website which will be available in French, English, Spanish and German, and I’d like to avoid common mistakes! :-)

I already read different blogs and post, and this is actually how I see the things for now:

- Regarding the URLs, I will use static routes which will associate each URL to a specific controller/action. This should allow me to have SEO friendly URL, and should be quite fast (I’ll not use regular expressions but compare the URLs parts to define the route to use).
  Note that I won’t have too many pages - probably less than 100 so the route shouldn’t be hard to define.
- Regarding the user interface, I’ll have one template per language in order to be able to be able to make adjustments (change the buttons, personnalize  the design for a specific country, …).
- I plan to use the database to store most of the website content (routes, menus, error messages, static page contents, page titles …).
  I will separate the localized content in different tables in order to minimize the size of each table.
  I chose this option in order to be able to easily edit the content using the GUI (since I want to allow admins to be able to change the translation if they want, without FTP or phpmyadmin access).
  I don’t expect any extra charge on the SQL server since the content which should be almost static (content pages, menus, error messages, route list, etc) will be cached, and the cache will be recreated only in case of content update via the GUI.

My question is the following:
- What do you think about my plan? Do you see important drawback regarding the choices that I did? Did I forget something important?

Thanks in advance!

NOTES:

- I don't plan to use a framework as I want to do the things by myself in order to improve my knowledge
- I'm already used to use UTF8 everywhere.
- I follow the MVC pattern.
- I'd like to avoid templating language, and keep only PHP in my views.

Comment: It seems that there will be a lot of code duplication if you create separate templates for every language. Just create one template and use some localization module (depends on what framework you are using) to print text and maybe some special css classes to change design (e.g. if you have <div class="content <?= echo language here ?>> and then in your css have .content.en{...} content.es{...} etc.

Comment: You are right. The idea was to keep the template as simple as possible, but if I see that most of its content is similar for each language, I'll use the same everywhere and just customize what I need via CSS.